# Identifier not found or unquie solidity

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "./simplestorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory {

    simplestorage[] public SimpleStorageArray;

    function createsimplestorageContract() public {
        simplestorage SimpleStorage = new simplestorage();

        SimpleStorageArray.push(SimpleStorage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Can you also share the `simplestorage.sol` file?

Comment: How can I share? I am new here...

Comment: You can use the `Edit` button below the question to add the code.